# How catch http data repsponce in test via Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, automated-tests, httpresponse, poltergeist

In app we use 3-th part service, what sometimes get broken. We regular testing app by Capybara, Poltergeist. But for tests be more specific in error log I need catch in tests data response from get/post api calls to that 3-th par service. I know about Poltergeist method `page.driver.network_traffic` but there are no data here, useful for me only `response.url` and `response.status` , but also I want somehow get data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Capybara is not suited or designed for API testing, see this blog post http://www.elabs.se/blog/34-capybara-and-testing-apis. There is no access to the get and post requests or responses without hacking the underlying code. Instead, try RackTest. RackTest was created to specifically test APIs: https://github.com/brynary/rack-test.

**Edit:** with rack-test the homepage documentation is not clear but you can use the Rack::Test::Methods mixin to get the response, see http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/Rack/Test/Methods.

For example:

```
require 'rack/test'

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
     MyApp.new
  end

  def my_test
    get '/'
    assert last_response.ok?
    assert_equal '<expected_response>', last_response.body
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks!, It's helpful a lot.